# How do you group comments by week start/end (period) date in django python>?

Tags: python, django

I'm developing a web app in django python that shows a list of all comments made on a particular project. What I want is to group comments by date so I can list them by week start/ending in the template, similar to what I have in the example below. Any help will surely be appreciated!

Example:

```
    Dataset = 
   {
      [
        period: '10/03/2016 - 10/07/2016', 
        comments: [ comments.object, comments.object, ...]
      ],
      [ 
        period: '10/10/2016 - 10/14/2016', 
        comments: [ comments.object, comments.object, ...],
      ],
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three possible approaches.

The holy grail would be to find a fancy expression that achieves this in annotations:

```
comments = Comment.objects.annotate(week_start_date=SomeFancyExpression('date')).order_by('week_start_date')
```

I can't do the above without a lot of thinking. I'm not even sure whether it's possible.

Secondly, if you think you're going to have large or expensive queries, you might like to denormalise the `week_start_date` attribute in your save method.

Thirdly, do it all in your view code. Here's a fairly crude way to achieve that:

```
import datetime
from django.db.models import Min, Max

comments = Comment.objects.aggregate(Min('date'), Max('date'))
min_week_start = comments['date__min'] - datetime.timedelta(comments['date__min'].weekday())
max_week_start = comments['date__max'] - datetime.timedelta(comments['date__max'].weekday())
num_weeks = (max_week_start - min_week_start).days // 7

# this may be off by one
weeks = (min_week_start + datetime.timedelta(days=7 * x) for x in range(0, num_weeks + 1))

grouped_comments = []
for week_start_date in weeks:
    grouped_comments.append(
        week_start_date,
        Comment.objects.filter(
            date__gte=week_start_date,
            date__lt=week_start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
        )
    )
```

This is one query for the max and min at the start, and one query per weekly group thereafter. If you can find a way to make method one work, that would be just a single query full stop.

(NB I've used 'future' division to calculate num_weeks. If you're on python 2, add `from __future__ import division` at the top)

Comment: Hey Nimasmi, appreciate your prompt response but it seems as if your third solution has an error. Please take into account that I'm relatively new @ django. Error "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'builtin_function_or_method'"

Comment: I've amended my lines 5 and 6 to fix this. Thanks for flagging. I've also fixed an int vs float issue in line 8, by using 'future' division. See NB at the end of my answer.